# How to dereference an array element (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, element, dereference

I wanted to create an array of a specific size using a variable, but allegedly the only way to do that is to use pointers.

```
int size = 5;
string* myArray = new string[size];
```

I now want to assign an element from this array to another variable, which I believe will only work through dereferencing. The following line of code doesn't work. How do I fix it?

```
string line;

myArray[0] = "Hello";
line = *myArray[0];
```

Edit:

I just want to clarify something: Using the normal "myArray[0]" code doesn't work either. It compiles, but causes a crash. Here's some more specific code regarding what I want to do.

```
void MyClass::setLine(string line)
{
    myLine = line; /*This is a private variable in MyClass*/
}

///////////////

MyClass* elements = new MyClass[size];

elements[0].setLine(myArray[0]);
```

I want to assign the array element to a private variable from a class, but the program crashes when I try to assign the value to the private variable.

Comment: `line = myArray[0];` I strongly suggest you use `vector<string> myArray(size);` instead as it will delete its own memory.

Comment: ...or if you have a fixed-size, use `std::array<std::string,5>` instead.

Comment: You might say "gives a compilation error" and paste the error message instead of saying "doesn't work". For this easy question it doesn't matter much, but it's generally a useful practice.

Comment: `myArray[0]` is already a dereference

Comment: It seems you have 2 arrays, and one of them has a problem... Debug a little to find out which, and ask a new question. Also, 3 people recommend replacing a pointer by `std::vector` and 1 person recommends replacing it by `std::array`. These are good suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the size at compile time, you can use a normal array. If you only know the size at runtime, you could still use a `std::vector`, which is far easier to use than manual allocation.

Anyway, if you really want to learn about pointers for array managing, keep in mind that the index operator is equivalent to addition and dereference, i.e. `ar[i]` is the same as `*(ar + i)`. In other words, indexing is just dereferencing at an offset.

As such, no extra dereference is needed. Just drop the asterisk in the failing line.

Answer (score 2):

Valid code will look like

```
string line;

myArray[0] = "Hello";
line = myArray[0];
```

By the way you could use class `std::vector` instead of the array if you are going to add or remove elements from the collection.

For example

```
std::vector<std::string> myArray;
myArrray.reserve( 5 );

myArray.push_back( "Hello" );

line = myArray[0];
```